# Android Marshmallow ScanSetting

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-6.0-marshmallow

I would like to build my scan settings in Android M so that I will get separate callbacks for three different events in one `ScanCallback` object:

1. When the remote device first matched the filter
2. When the Android phone received advertisements after the first discovery (In this case I am checking if advertisement data has changed or not)
3. When the remote device is out of range

There are three options in the *API*:

```
CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES  
CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH  
CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST
```

Unfortunately, there is not a good documentation about whether these three options can all be used together or not. According to my experiments, I should choose only one of them. Does the API require from us to separate simultaneous scans to get callback for `CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES`  and `CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST` at the same time? Does anyone have any good experience on how to use these options?

**EDIT**:

After checking *API* source code I found out that `CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH | CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST` is also a valid combination. However, using `CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH` makes it significantly slower (~30 seconds) to discover compared to `CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES`. Furthermore, `CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST` is called although the device is actively advertising. I don't think that this *API* is reliable.

Here are my results:

> 12:02:50.179 31627-31655 D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
>   12:03:24.877 31627-31627 D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow: ScanResult{mDevice=E8:A8:C9:82:17:61, ...}
>   12:03:24.878 31627-31627 D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow: CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH
>   12:03:29.905 31627-31627 D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow: ScanResult{mDevice=C0:B6:43:1E:45:28, ...}
>   12:03:29.906 31627-31627 D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow: CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH
>   12:03:39.721 31627-31627 D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow: ScanResult{mDevice=D8:35:26:9D:55:B4, ...}
>   12:03:39.722 31627-31627 D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow: CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH
>
> 12:04:21.889 718-730 D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() -
>   status=0 clientIf=6   12:04:22.073 718-718 D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow:
>   ScanResult{mDevice=D8:35:26:9D:55:B4, ...}   12:04:22.073 718-718
>   D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow: CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES   12:04:22.316
>   718-718 D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow:
>   ScanResult{mDevice=E8:A8:C9:82:17:61, ...}   12:04:22.316 718-718
>   D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow: CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES   12:04:24.740
>   718-718 D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow:
>   ScanResult{mDevice=E8:A8:C9:82:17:61, ...}   12:04:24.740 718-718
>   D/ScanCallbackMarshmallow: CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES

**EDIT 2**:

Setting the scan mode as `ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY` makes the discovery using `CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH` as fast as using `CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES`. However, If I set the callback type as `ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH | ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST` I will not be able to check if the advertisement data has changed or not in case the advertisement data is dynamic. I think this is the problem with the API. It should be noted that that Advertisement data is not predictable so I can not filter the advertisement data based on its content.

Comment: For my devices, I've found that if I use `ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH | ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST` or `ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH` then the device name is always null. If I use CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES, then the device name is read as expected...